# Record navigator from jsf datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, navigation, record

I require some advice on a query regarding record navigation.
I have a datatable that is displayed with the results of an Hibernate query. The datatable looks something like this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.dataList}" var="dataItem">
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="ID" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{dataItem.id}" />
</h:column>
```

The user then selects a row and it displays a form with the details on a JSF form.
What I would like to do is allow the user to go to the next row in the results table from the JSF form without going 'back' to the results table.

Is this possible?

Comment: You have myBean.dataList and item ID. The next row represents next item in dataList. If you need display for that item (in your form), then reset item ID (for next row) and refresh view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a ajax call on click of Next button present on the form. When the user presses Next, on default event "action", you can write code in a managed bean method which will be called through the listener property of f:ajax. in this method call, you can set the values of different fields on the form depending on the Id of the next record. These values may be used by different components on your form.

```
<h:commandButton value="Next">

    <f:ajax event="action" execute="@this" render="@form" listener="#{myBean.populateNextRecord}"/>

</h:commandButton>
```